# jstree trim long text

Tags: html, jstree, css

I have created a jstree.

There may be a node with very long label, such as - **qwerewurweuirwerweurwerwerwerewrwerwerewr**. In such case I want that label to be breaked into like this **qwerewurwe...**

`text-overflow: ellipsis` effect

Here is my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/juyMR/

In my fiddle `text-overflow: ellipsis` is not working. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to add this:

```
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
```

And you should have set a width to your container